# python - how to update every element in an array to increase the mean of the data

Tags: python, numpy, audio, mean, data-manipulation

I have audio data that I normalized between -4 and 4; however, I need the "center" of the wave / data (mean?) to be centered at "1" (please see the attached figure)

How can I manipulate my list of data where the mean is translated / converted to be ~1? While still maintaining a normalization of -4 to 4

Is there an easy way to do this using numpy?

[image]

Comment: increase every value by `1 - current_mean`

Comment: it seems to me you just need to add DC value to the signal, in simpler term need to add around +2.5 to level up the signal to 1. You can calculate the avg value of the signal then (1-avg) will be what you need to add

Comment: check this https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40780/how-to-get-the-fourier-series-using-pythons-tt-fft

Comment: @MZ I like the idea of increasing every value by `1 - current_mean`, but then my data is no longer normalized between -4 and 4 as every element has shifted up; perhaps I should have stated that requirement in the question

Comment: From the figure you provided it looks like you can simply take `new_value = -old_value` to me (I presume that the sign doesn't play a role in the audio data?).

Comment: @sams-studio In isolation, no, the sign doesn't matter (it's equivalent to shifting the phase of a signal by 180 degrees), but if played together with the original sound instead of being +3dB it cancels destructively.

Answer (score 0):

In the future it would be nice if you provided an example to tinker with. The second problem is that you don't tell us what type of function to use or what properties it should preserve. Since there clearly is no linear function that does what you want I am going with a quadratic one. But first here is my "sound" to tinker with

```
np.random.seed(1)
x = np.linspace(0,0.01,10**4)
y = 0.1*np.sin(50*2*np.pi*x/(0.01))+np.random.random()*np.sin(50*2*np.pi*x/(0.01))*((0.0067<x)&(x<0.007))+((0.0067<x)&(x<0.007))*0.2
y -= y.mean()
plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image: example sound]

It is not quite your original one but has the property that after centering it is not between -1 and 1. Since it seems more clean I will center to zero and range -1 and 1 but that should make no real difference. My plan was to pick the unique quadratic function that maps the maximum to 1, the minimum to -1 and pick a good value to send 0 to i.e. one for which the mean is zero.

```
import sympy
a,b,c = sympy.symbols('a, b, c')

def change_scale(arr, lamb=0):
    m = arr.min()
    M = arr.max()
    eqns = [a*x**2+b*x+c-y for x,y in zip([m,0,M],[-1,lamb,1])]
    sols = sympy.solve(eqns,[a,b,c])
    d,e,f = map(np.float64, sols.values())

    return d*arr**2+e*arr+f
    
y2 = change_scale(y)
print(y2.mean())
plt.plot(x,y2)
```

[image: ranged but not centered]

To me this almost looks good. The only problem is that now the mean is `-0.015`. Well but for that we have that lambda parameter.

A quick check shows that 0.5 would be to big and -0.5 would be to small meaning this is a perfect job for `scipy.optimize.bisect`.

```
from scipy.optimize import bisect
lamb = bisect(lambda x: change_scale(y,x).mean(),0.5,-0.5)
```

gives us the perfect value for lambda. The picture looks like so

[image: perfect scale and perfect mean]

Which is exactly what I expected since. The mean was slightly too small so we moved things up a bit. Now the mean is zero, the max is 1 and the min is -1.

As a final sanity check we can plot the function we actually applied to our values:

[image: data transformation function]